# How to change my.large.ini to my.ini

Tags: mysql

I want to improve my mysql performance. So I tried to use my-large.ini.

First I rename that file to my.ini.
Then I added following lines under [mysqld]

```
port=3306
basedir="C:/Program Files/MySQL/MySQL Server 5.1/"
datadir="C:/Documents and Settings/All Users/Application Data/MySQL/MySQL Server 5.1/Data/"
```

After that I tried to start my mysql service. Its not starting.

Any more changes I need to do to configure that.
Please help me.

Thanks

Comment: What is the error in the mysql error log? Did you check that each line of `my-large.ini` was correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that datadir for you shoud be

```
datadir="C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.1\data\"
```